# Arranging bytes in a packet

Tags: c++, packet, socks

If I need to create a packet like this:

```
field 1: SOCKS protocol version, 1 byte 
field 2: status, 1 byte: 
field 3: reserved, must be 0x00
field 4: address type, 1 byte: 
field 5: destination address of 
         1 byte of name length followed by the name for Domain name
field 6: network byte order port number, 2 bytes

char packet[6];   
packet[0] = 5;   
packet[1] = 0;   
packet[2] = 0;  
packet[3] = 1;   
packet[4] = /* ... ???? ... */;
packet[5] = 80;`
```

How do I write the `packet[4]` (field 5) for `www.google.com`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the sockets library functions to do this for you?  Manually writing packets is hard, but if you have to do it manually then you have to do it manually.

Comment: sorry,what functions will do this automatly ?

Comment: I create a class similar to [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) of the .NET framework. Think of it like a stringstream, except it breaks everything down into a series of bytes automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have what you want you can't have each field as a specific fixed index in the packet array because each position can only hold atmost one byte. You'd have to do something like this:

```
char address[] = "www.google.com";
int addressLen = strlen(address);
char* packet = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*6+addressLen);
int i;

packet[0] = 5;
...
packet[3] = 1;
packet[4] = addressLen;

for (i = 0; i < addressLen; i++) 
   packet[i + 5] = address[i];

packet[4 + addressLen] = 80;
```

EDIT: Actually I made this example for C. Should work in C++ aswell but I don't know the interface of the network library you're using. That malloc probably could be replaced by a new. Or you could use the standard containers since I think those can be accessed as an array aswell.

Comment: @Revolt: and if i get a packet like this,how can I print the "www.google.com" part from it, i tried using a for loop and print (char*)&packet[i + 5] but it gives me this: www.g
ww.g
w.g
.g
g

Comment: To print the address in the received packet you got to first read packet[4] to know how many bytes you have to read to get the address. Then you need a for (i = 0; i < packet[4]; i++) printf(packet[5+i]). Oh and please note that using my code the '\0' won't be transmitted in the packet so you'll have to add it at the reception if you want a valid string.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 14; ++i)
    {
     cout << (char*)&temp[i + 5] << endl;;
    }

Comment: if your temp is of type char* you don't need that cast. In fact you shouldn't use it. In your code you want to print each character one at a time so you should print temp[i+5] and not a pointer to temp[i+5] (C++ will try to print that as a string if I'm not mistaken and you didn't add the '\0')

Comment: Ok,but know,i get this message from the client(i am the server) so i need to get the string part from it,because after i need to send a similar packet back to the client(your code). But it still not prints good,even if i use printf("%c", packet[i + 5] or if i use cout.

Comment: If that printf doesn't print the string correctly chances are you have a problem on the actual transfer. What is the output of that prinf? And if you want to copy that address to a string instead of printing, allocate a new char* array (with size specified by temp[4]) and copy each character from one array to the other.

Comment: www.g and a strange character.thats it

Comment: The reason it doesnt print the string is because hes printing a character. I think you're looking for `printf("%s", &packet[i + 5]);`. It has to be null-terminated though.

Comment: @Marlon Thing is he is printing character by character in a for over all entries of the address. It should work. @vBx It seems that your program is only transferring 5 of the bytes of the address. In your socket code you probably have a packetlen parameter. This should be the same size as your packet array.

Comment: but one more silly question,it doesnt print it on the screen when its running,only when i stop the program it pops on the screen,why i sthat ?

Comment: Well, can't really say... Maybe your cout is buffered or something? Can't say much more without seeing details of the code and how the actual socket/communication library you use works.

Comment: if i put a cout << endl; after the foor loop it prints it, now i need to test the other way around,to send a packet using your code,if i have problem,i will post here

Comment: Oh yeah. Maybe it doesn't print it right away because of the missing '\0'. Don't remember the inner workings of C++ streams.

Comment: instead of printing it,i want to save it to a buffer,isnt this code good? char domain[100]; memset(domain, '\0', sizeof(domain));for(int i = 0; i < 14; ++i)
    {
     //cout << temp[i + 5];
     sprintf(domain, "%c", temp[i + 5]);
    } I get only on "m" printed

Comment: Nope that won't work. You need something like this: char* domain = (char*) malloc(temp[4]*sizeof(char) + 1); for (int i = 0; i < temp[4]; i++) { domain[i] = temp[i + 5];} domain[i] = '\0';

Comment: @vBx, Are you able to use a debugger? If so, try using breakpoints to see how your code executes. This will help you fix problems.

Comment: @Marlon: yes debuger its very helpfull,but i dont know how to use breakpoints,i should learn,yes

Comment: @Revolt: it works,but i need to alocate space only for the size of temp[4] without +1 and that last statement should be domain[temp[4]] = '\0':) If i add +1 when i alocate memory it will print www.google.com/ with a "/" at the end.

Comment: actually you do need the +1 so you can include the terminating '\0' otherwise it won't be a valid string. I can't see how by adding +1 a "/" would magically appear unless that "/" was also transferred as part of the address.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need more than six bytes, certainly.  One straightforward option is to use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
v.push_back(5);
v.push_back(0);
v.push_back(0);
v.push_back(1);

std::string address = "www.google.com";
v.push_back(address.size());
std::copy(address.begin(), address.end(), std::back_inserter(v));

v.push_back(80);

// data is accessible as an array by using &v[0]
```

Comment: @Downvoter:  Is there something technically incorrect in this answer?  If there is, I am happy to correct the answer or remove it, but if you don't comment to explain what is wrong with the answer in the first place, it's impossible for me to do that.